# Assign value to axes Joy message

Tags: ros, joy-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
my problem is that I got a segmentation fault when I assign a value to the axes of a joy message.

Here I post my code:

```
sensor_msgs::Joy out;
double linear_, angular_;

out.axes[1] = linear_;
out.axes[3] = angular_;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261374/assign-value-to-axes-joy-message/) by [tonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/30285/tonio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm assuming this is C++.

Most likely `out.axes` -- a `std::vector` -- currently has a zero-length, and you're trying to assign values to the first and third element. That leads to your program trying to access memory it does not have access to, which leads to `SEGFAULT`s. See [std::vector - operator []](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at).

You either have to use `.reserve(..)`, use `.push_back(..)` or use one of the c'tors of `std::vector` that initialises it with sufficient capacity.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-09**:
PS: this is really a C++ question. We're happy to help, but please keep in mind that ROS Answers is not a generic programming support forum.

**Comment by [tonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/30285/tonio/) on 2017-05-09**:
Sorry, I didn't know! :) By the way, thanks for the answer, it's helped!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-09**:
Glad to hear it worked.

And no problem, just keep it in mind.